# Adding Precision Strike to an attack with advantage

Tags: dnd-5e, advantage-and-disadvantage

I want to make sure I have the ruling on this correct.

> -Precision Attack- When you make a weapon attack roll against a creature, you can expend one superiority die to add it to the roll.
>   You can use this maneuver before **or after** making the attack roll, but
>   before any effects of the attack are applied.

This means that if I'm attacking with advantage, I can roll both d20's, and the decide which of those (obvious the higher) to add my d8 to, just to further cinch the hit if I'm against an uber-evasive/heavily-armored opponent.

Comment: Good, I didn't mess that up. :D

Answer (score 13):

Just to break it down, here's how attack rolls work:

> When
>   you
>   make
>   an
>   attack,
>   your
>   attack
>   roll
>   determines
>   whether
>   the
>   attack
>   hits
>   or
>   misses.
>   To
>   make
>   an
>   attack
>   roll,
>   roll
>   a
>   d20
>   and
>   add
>   the
>   appropriate
>   modifiers.

And here's how advantage changes that:

> Sometimes
>   a
>   special
>   ability
>   or
>   spell
>   tells
>   you
>   that
>   you
>   have
>   advantage
>   or
>   disadvantage
>   on
>   an
>   ability
>   check,
>   a
>   saving
>   throw,
>   or
>   an
>   attack
>   roll.
>   When
>   that
>   happens,
>   you
>   roll
>   a
>   second
>   d20
>   when
>   you
>   make
>   the
>   roll.
>   Use
>   the
>   higher
>   of
>   the
>   two
>   rolls
>   if
>   you
>   have
>   advantage,
>   and
>   use
>   the
>   lower
>   roll
>   if
>   you
>   have
>   disadvantage.

Putting these together, we get this: When
you
make
an
attack,
your
attack
roll
determines
whether
the
attack
hits
or
misses.
To
make
an
attack
roll,
roll
two
d20s and use the higher roll, then
add
the
appropriate
modifiers.

So, even if you chose to roll your d8 before you made the roll, it would still get added to the higher roll. Of course, as you say, you can decide to use the d8 after you've already made the roll, which is to say, after you've rolled 2 d20s, used the highest, and added the appropriate modifiers to it.